# Esc key of a Apple Magic external keyboard doesn't work in Linux and Windows

Tags: keyboard, unix

I'm using a Mac Bluetooth keyboard (model A1314) in my Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.3, and it is fine except for the Esc key. Sometimes it works properly, others it doesn't work and others I need to press 3-5 times the key to have a response.

As you can imagine, it is very frustrating because when it doesn't work I need to press the inbuilt Esc key of my laptop, breaking my programming flux.

Today It was not working but recently it started to work intermittent, so I take advantage of it to run the xev command and got this result:

Mac keyboard:

> KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
> root 0x257, subw 0x0, time 20707755, (78,100), root:(2048,180),
> state 0x2000, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
> XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
> mbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
> FilterEvent returns: False

Internal keyboard:

> KeyRelease event, serial 49, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
> root 0x257, subw 0x0, time 20707861, (78,100), root:(2048,180),
> state 0x2000, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
> XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) " FilterEvent returns: False

It tried it also in my Android and the behavior was the same. In my windows partition it didn't work, but I think that in other moment it could work like in Ubuntu and Android.

I discard a hardware damage because all the other keys work perfectly, and it doesn't show any signal of damage.

What could be the problem? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: When you say "Mac Bluetooth Keyboard", do you mean the Magic Keyboard? If you do, you might want to edit the question so that that is more obvious